# php laravel 5.3 password forgot

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying this code for forgotten password, but it does not work.

This is the route part view folder:

```
Route::get('password/reset/{token?}','Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('password/email','Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
/*Route::post('password/reset','Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');*/
```

this is also the 
extends('layout')

```
@section('header')

@stop

@section('content')

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div slass="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-header"> reset password

                    <div class="panel-body">
                    {{!! Form::open(['url' => 'password/email'])!!}}
                    {{!! Form::lable('email','Email address')}}
                    {{Form::email('email',null),['class'=>'form-control']}}

                    {{ Form::submit('Reset Password',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}

                    {{form::close();

                    </div>              

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
@stop

@section('footer')

@stop
```

Comment: iam not sure if the route is heading to the right controllers. if some one has a better tutorial link for forgot password laravel 5.3. i would apperciate!

Comment: Can you specify what doesn't work? 
Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: gat them fixed tns..... it was my error